# How do I direct JavaScript to a function on a satisfied IF statement? Trying to fix an Alert loop after progress bar completion

Tags: javascript

This is a very basic question, and for some reason I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around it. I am new and learning so bear with me please.

Here is a progress bar: https://codepen.io/cmpackagingllc/pen/ZNExoa

When the bar has loaded completely it adds the class completed as seen on js line 41.

```
progress.bar.classList.add('completed');
```

So say once completed I want to add an Alert that say's "completed". I assume this would be an easy task but because of the way the code is written with the loop seen on line 46/47

```
  loop();
}, randomInterval);
```

I am unable to incorporate the Alert properly without an alert loop even when I used return false to stop the loop afterwards.

So the route I am trying to take now is to add the alert prompt to the success function found on line 21-25

```
function success() {
  progress.width = progress.bar.offsetWidth;
  progress.bar.classList.add('completed');
  clearInterval(setInt);
  alert("Completed!");
}
```

But now I am stuck trying to format it correctly so when the if is called on line 36

```
if (progress.width >= progress.bar.offsetWidth) {
```

When the if is called on line 36 I want to to jump to the success function instead. No matter how I try it the code fails to execute. How would I format this correctly so it jumps to my function instead of looping after completed?

I would greatly appreciate some assistance with this. I am trying to understand if there is a better way to add the alert. Thank you much.

Comment: Where did you get that code? It doesn't make much sense. For one, it's creating multiple timers, all of which call `success` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your code with special attention because recently I have been working with some loading bars (but not animated ones).

The problem is that you are using `setTimeout()` and not `setInterval()`, so calling `clearInterval()` has no effect at all. And you really don't need `setInterval()` because you're already making recursive calls (looping by calling the same function from its body).

I've took the liberty of rewriting your code for you to analyse it. Please let me know if you have any doubts.

NOTE: It's easier in this case to use relative units for the width! So you don't have to calculate "allowance".

```
let progress = {
    fill: document.querySelector(".progress-bar .filler"),
    bar: document.querySelector(".progress-bar"),
    width: 0
};

(function loop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        progress.width += Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        if (progress.width >= 100) {
            progress.fill.style.width = '100%';
            progress.bar.classList.add('completed');
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('COMPLETED!');
            }, 500);
        } else {
            progress.fill.style.width = `${progress.width}%`;
            loop();
        }
    }, Math.round(Math.random() * (1400 - 500)) + 500);
})();
```

Comment: To be precise... `clearInterval()` is a shared method of `setInterval()` and `setTimeout`, in the latter it will abort the timer, so it makes sense to call it only before the timer has finished (not inside the callback).

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I got everything working great, I really appreciate it again. However I noticed you added "let progress" I can only get this to work using var. Is their an advantage to let?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I added let unconsciously, it's now the recommended way to declare variables. The difference is in scope: `var` will be hoisted to the nearest function block, `let` instead will be hoisted to the nearest code block `{}` of any kind. Using `let` avoids variables scopes conflicts by having a narrower scope. You can use `var` and there will be absolutely no difference in this case. Check your environment support if you want to use `let`.

Answer (score 1):

Like a comment said, there are several timers in your code. Also, `success` was never executed. Here you have a version that works.

If you are learning, try to make your code as simple as possible, use pseudocode to see in wich step there is an error and try debugging from there.

```js
var progress = {
  fill: document.querySelector(".progress-bar .filler"),
  bar: document.querySelector(".progress-bar"),
  width: 0 };


function setSize() {
  var allowance = progress.bar.offsetWidth - progress.width;
  var increment = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
  progress.width += increment > allowance ? allowance : increment;
  progress.fill.style.width = String(progress.width + "px");
}

function success() {
  progress.width = progress.bar.offsetWidth;
  progress.bar.classList.add('completed');
  alert("Completed!");
}

(function loop() {
  var randomInterval = Math.round(Math.random() * (1400 - 500)) + 500;
  var setInt = setTimeout(function () {
    setSize();
    if (progress.width >= progress.bar.offsetWidth) {
      success();
    } else { 
      loop();
    }
  }, randomInterval);
})();
```

```css
 .progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D2DCE5;
}
.progress-bar.completed .filler {
  background: #0BD175;
}
.progress-bar.completed .filler:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.progress-bar .filler {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
  background: #00AEEF;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}
.progress-bar .filler:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #00AEEF, #00AEEF 10px, #23c3ff 10px, #23c3ff 20px);
  height: 10px;
  width: 700px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: fill 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fill {
  from {
    transform: translatex(-350px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="progress-bar">
  <span class="filler"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: It must be why I was so confused, I wasn't sure what was going on there. This is from a snippet I found on codepen. I can't fine the original source as it was some time ago. None the less I greatly do appreciate the help. You cleaned it up so well, it's much easier to read and understand what's going on now. I was getting a headache over this.

Comment: @JasonWaltz Great! I'm glad I could help you.